# How to render data using chartjs in expressJS

Tags: node.js, express, charts, chart.js

I'm kinda lost with using ChartJS. I'm trying to render a chart that uses dynamic data from a database (mongoDB). I've looked into Chart docs and built some static graphs, but I'm struggling to find a good approach to fetch and render the data. My idea is to use the chart to show data on a daily basis.

I've seen two things that seem to work: AJAX requests or using db.collection.find() from mongo, passing the JSON to array and using this to fetch the data.

How to pass the data to Chart? Do I have to create a var data = data fetched from db or something like that?

I'm not looking for code, I'm just looking for some guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got that right. You can declare the data fetched from the DB as a JSON object and pass it to your Chart. Like so,

```
 var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labelsObject,
      datasets: dataObject
    },
    options: chart_ops
  });
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll check it out. I'm a little bit lost because I intend to render the graph on a route called /home, I didn't build an API to fetch the data. I guess that your solution will work, appreciate your help!